# Web.config files for SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, web-config

What's the different between web.config files under the project and the one under **C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories** in SharePoint Project.

Is it the same ?

Let's say if I want to use an assembly, where should I put it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint? What project template you use? Why you want to add assembly (i.e. some custom http module or reference in your project)?

Comment: SharePoint 2010. Empty SharePoint Project I guess. Assembly is just an example.
Let's say if I want to use report viewer , i have to put some configuration info in web.config. I don't know which one is the right one to put.

Comment: If report viewer control is not registered when you installed SSRS (in SharePoint integrated mode, I suppose), you should add it to the web.config of SharePoint web site/application (wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\portnumber) where you want to use it. I would put that file under version control, as you will probably want to know all changes you made to it someday.

Comment: Thanks for the tip of putting the file under version control.
So the Web.Config file under my project is nothing ?

Comment: well, I did not do much with 2010, but in 2007 there deployment of projects was big PITA, and I mostly deployed by putting project dll into GAC and changing web.config by hand. I did not write answer as I don't remember how it was in 2010 (I haven't worked much with it). You could save current web.config, deploy project and use i.e. notepad++ with compare plugin to check if deployment properly adds your specifics to web.config

Answer (score 2):

Anything put in the web.config of C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories is connected to the SharePoint web and that web alone. The web.config in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\ (and the hive folders) are connected to either the Layout templates or the services that are running sharepoint.

If you want to register an assembly put it in the web.config of C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories

Comment: How about normal AppSetting ? Can I use any of these ?
Sorry I don't see it clearly.